# After power failure SSD behaves strangely

Tags: ssd, fsck

SSD contains 2 partitions. I can't mount root partition(ext3) and can mount home(ext4), but I can't fsck any of them, I get same "fsck.ext(3,4) Input/output error" for each.
I'm sure there was minor or not at all reading/writing on disk during power failure.

I want to know what I can do about it? How can it be that I can mount partiotion, but fsck returns error.
Is SSD corrupt? It's about 2.5 y.o. and worked well so far.

**I reinstalled system, ssd works 3 weeks already**.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Make a LIVE CD/DVD (or bootable USB stick) with a new version of fsck then try to fix the root partition.  Maybe OpenSuse or ubuntu

Comment: With new version of fsck it did checked and fixed huge amount of sectors, afterwards I mounted partition and there were nothing but lost&found. I'm bewildered because home partition remained intact and fine.

Comment: Each partition is like its own box, and damage to one partition's file system has no effect on the other.  This is partly why home exists as a partition as it contains user created content.  You can re-install an OS, but not a word document.  When the power failed it obviously was writing to the 1st partition and some of the file system was lost because of this.

Comment: So, as I understood you think I can reinstall OS and use ssd subsequently?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your SSD may have died.    take what you can get off it, get a new disk, reinstall and put the stuff back.

You might want to try using ddrescue to get as much of the disk as possible onto a new disk, then fsck the copy.     Alternatively, you might just be able to copy your home dir and that might do you ???  I do note that you should not fsck a mounted partition (not sure if you were trying to do this, hopefully you wern't).

Comment: I do have backups, so it isn't a problem of getting data out of it. I didn't fsck mounted partition. Just want to be sure that ssd is dead.